# springboot embeded tomcat Acceptor thread missing

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot, spring-rest

We are using springboot ***1.3.3.RELEASE*** with embedded tomcat.
The service is running on redhat Linux 2.6.32 (64bit), using java 1.8.0_45.

In our load environment we noticed that the server is up (java VM is still running) and responding to non-HTTP requests, but HTTP requests exposed via SpringMVC Rest do not work, we get timeout.

After comparing thread dump between healthy and not-healthy system, we noticed in a non-healthy system the  *http-nio-{port}-Acceptor* thread is missing.

In particular the dump shown bellow from a healthy machine is missing from bad one.

> "http-nio-8080-Acceptor-0" #45 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0
>   tid=0x00007f13fb9ef800 nid=0x896b runnable [0x00007f146f3f4000]
>   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>                  at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
>                  at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:422)
>                  at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:250)
>                  - locked <0x00000005cd5d0558> (a java.lang.Object)
>                  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Acceptor.run(NioEndpoint.java:682)
>                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

What could be reasons for the Acceptor thread to be missing?
Is it possible to restart the threat, without restarting the whole application? 
Is that the reason we are not able to service HTTP requests?